# Paraxial diffraction

Tags: optics, diffraction, structural-beam

I got some work to do at a lab, but I am quite stuck with this task:
Gaussian beam at a plane $z=0$ is $f=\exp[-(x^2+y^2)/d]$. Evalute the formula at a plane $z=z_0$ using paraxial diffraction theory. 
I do not need you to solve it for me , I just need some help and maybe an explanation or some information (literature) on what should i do.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hi! If I remember correctly, the propagation of a certain field distribution can be found in Goodman's "Introduction to Fourier Optics". I am not sure if you a more specific analysis of the propagation of gaussian beams can be found in O. Svelto, "Principles of Lasers". If I find my notes about it, I'll write an answer!

Comment: One question: are you sure of how the gaussian beam is written? I think there is an $ik$ missing in the exponential, with $i$ imaginary unit and $k$ wave vector.

Comment: Thank you, tomorrow will search these books up.
Oops, sorry, my bad!  Task says, it is not a beam, it is a Gaussian distribution which is described by that function. But, i will ask my supervisor if there are no mistakes.

Comment: Ok, then maybe the first reference is better!